# Parallel processing in golang

Tags: parallel-processing, go, goroutine

Given the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go f(i)
    }

    // prevent main from exiting immediately
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}

func f(n int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        dowork(n, i)
        amt := time.Duration(rand.Intn(250))
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * amt)
    }
}

func dowork(goroutine, loopindex int) {
    // simulate work
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(5))
    fmt.Printf("gr[%d]: i=%d\n", goroutine, loopindex)
}
```

Can i assume that the 'dowork' function will be executed in parallel?

Is this a correct way of achieving parallelism or is it better to use channels and separate 'dowork' workers for each goroutine?

Comment: Just in case anyone finds it interesting: [This article](http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/parallel-for-loop) explains how to do parallel for loops in Go.

Comment: @rath Many thanks - that website will prove a fantastic resource for me!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**This answer is outdated. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403016/115363) instead.**

---

Your code will run concurrently, but not in parallel. You can make it run in parallel by setting `GOMAXPROCS`.

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here, but it looks like a perfectly valid way of achieving concurrency to me.

Comment: I followed the above mentioned article example. I am not getting same output. methods are getting executed sequentially not parallel.

Answer (score 32):

Regarding `GOMAXPROCS`, you can find this in Go 1.5's release docs:

> By default, Go programs run with GOMAXPROCS set to the number of cores available; in prior releases it defaulted to 1.

Regarding preventing the `main` function from exiting immediately, you could leverage `WaitGroup`'s `Wait` function.

I wrote this utility function to help parallelize a group of functions:

```
import "sync"

// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(f func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            f()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

So in your case, we could do this

```
func1 := func() {
    f(0)
}

func2 = func() {
    f(1)
}

func3 = func() {
    f(2)
}

Parallelize(func1, func2, func3)
```

If you wanted to use the Parallelize function, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util

Comment: Is it possible to make parallel SQL queries with this?

Comment: I would avoid using `copy` as a variable name, because it overrides a predeclared identifier: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

`f()` will be executed concurrently but many `dowork()` will be executed sequentially within each `f()`. Waiting on stdin is also not the right way to ensure that your routines finished execution. You must spin up a channel that each `f()` pushes a `true` on when the `f()` finishes. 
At the end of the `main()` you must wait for n number of `true`'s on the channel. n being the number of `f()` that you have spun up.

Comment: `sync.WaitGroup` is better than a channel for that case.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when I was starting out.

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func put(number chan<- int, count int) {
        i := 0
        for ; i <= (5 * count); i++ {
            number <- i
        }
        number <- -1
    }

    func subs(number chan<- int) {
        i := 10
        for ; i <= 19; i++ {
            number <- i
        }
    }

    func main() {
        channel1 := make(chan int)
        channel2 := make(chan int)
        done := 0
        sum := 0

        go subs(channel2)
        go put(channel1, 1)
        go put(channel1, 2)
        go put(channel1, 3)
        go put(channel1, 4)
        go put(channel1, 5)

        for done != 5 {
            select {
            case elem := <-channel1:
                if elem < 0 {
                    done++
                } else {
                    sum += elem
                    fmt.Println(sum)
                }
            case sub := <-channel2:
                sum -= sub
                fmt.Printf("atimta : %d\n", sub)
                fmt.Println(sum)
            }
        }
        close(channel1)
        close(channel2)
    }
```

"Conventional cluster-based systems (such as supercomputers) employ parallel execution between processors using MPI. MPI is a communication interface between processes that execute in operating system instances on different processors; it doesn't support other process operations such as scheduling. (At the risk of complicating things further, because MPI processes are executed by operating systems, a single processor can run multiple MPI processes and/or a single MPI process can also execute multiple threads!)"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loop at the end, to block until the jobs are done:

```
package main
import "time"

func f(n int, b chan bool) {
   println(n)
   time.Sleep(time.Second)
   b <- true
}

func main() {
   b := make(chan bool, 9)
   for n := cap(b); n > 0; n-- {
      go f(n, b)
   }
   for <-b {
      if len(b) == 0 { break }
   }
}
```