# How to achieve proper parallelism in Golang? Are goroutines parallel in versions 1.5+?

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I know the differences between parallelism and concurrency. I'm looking for how to achieve parallelism in Go. I expected goroutines to be parallel, but the documentation I found appears to say otherwise.

The setting GOMAXPROCS allows us to configure the number of threads that the application can use to run in parallel. Since version 1.5, GOMAXPROCS has as value the number of cores. As far as I understand, goroutines are inherently parallel since version 1.5. Is this conclusion correct?

Every question I find on sites like StackOverflow appears to be outdated and doesn't take into account this change in version 1.5. See: [Parallel processing in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106526/parallel-processing-in-golang)

My confusion arises from trying to test this parallelism in practice. I have tried the following code I in Go 1.10 and it doesn't run in parallel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    wg.Add(2)
    go count()
    go count()
    wg.Wait()

}

func count() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Setting up GOMAXPROCS to 2 doesn't change the result. I get a concurrent program instead of a parallel one.

I'm running all my tests on an 8 core system.

**Edit**: For future reference,

I got carried away by this blog: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html where parallelism is achieved without much hassle in a small for-loop. The answer by @peterSO is completely valid. For some reason, in Go 1.10 I couldn't replicate the results of the blog.

Comment: Your test program isn't very robust. It's too short/fast, one of the go routines could finish in the blink of an eye long before the other go routine is started and gets scheduled to run. Change your loop to iterate a few tens of thousand times

Comment: You and peterSO are absolutely right. My code was too short. For the record, I got carried away by this blog: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html

Where it clearly shows parallelism working with a small for loop that I couldn't replicate either, so I simplified the example.

Comment: JFTR, goroutines were parallel since day 0, just the defaults changed in 1.5. Before that, you could make your Go program see the `GOMAXPROCS` env. variable set to something greater than 1 to make it use that much OS threads to multiplex the execution of goroutines. Reading [this](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) and  [this](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/) is very much advised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Go Playground is a single-processor virtual machine. You are running a trivial goroutine. Toy programs run on toy machines get toy results.

Run this on a multiple CPU machine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func count() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
        i := 0
        for ; i < 1e6; i++ {
        }
        _ = i
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Version", runtime.Version())
    fmt.Println("NumCPU", runtime.NumCPU())
    fmt.Println("GOMAXPROCS", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
    wg.Add(2)
    go count()
    go count()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

```
Version go1.10
NumCPU 8
GOMAXPROCS 8
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
```

Comment: can you explain how this output shows that its executing in parallel and not just concurrently on a single thread? Thanks

Comment: peterSo has 8 cores and two threads per core, each thread is printing what core it belongs to.

Comment: @BrandonRaeder that's not what this code is doing. Each goroutine is incrementing its version of `i`, printing it, then doing some "work".
You can see this running in parallel through `top` / Task Manager etc.