# Make it faster solving?

Tags: python

I am running this on i7 8th Gen. But it looks too slow to process compared to the processor.

## Is there any way that I can improve the performance of my script? the average CPU is only at 10-20% usage. So I'm seeking your guys help. If you have any suggestions, please don't hesitate.

```
import os
import sys
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

PATH = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/')
ADD_PATH = PATH + '/models/research'

sys.path.insert(0, ADD_PATH)

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'labelmap.pbtxt'
NUM_CLASSES = 37

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

def load_model():
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
            with detection_graph.as_default():
                config = tf.ConfigProto()
                if os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] == '-1':
                    #cpu
                    print("few")
                    #config.inter_op_parallelism_threads = 4
                    #config.intra_op_parallelism_threads = 4
                else:
                    #gpu
                    print("few")
                    #config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
                    #config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1.0

                config.log_device_placement = False
                sess = tf.Session(config=config, graph=detection_graph)
                return sess, detection_graph

def inference(sess, detection_graph, img_arr, average_distance_error=3):
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(img_arr, axis=0)
        # Actual detection.
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

        # Bellow we do filtering stuff
        captcha_array = []
        # loop our all detection boxes
        for i,b in enumerate(boxes[0]):
            for Symbol in range(37):
                if classes[0][i] == Symbol: # check if detected class equal to our symbols
                    if scores[0][i] >= 0.30: # do something only if detected score more han 0.65
                                        # x-left        # x-right
                        mid_x = (boxes[0][i][1]+boxes[0][i][3])/2 # find x coordinates center of letter
                        # to captcha_array array save detected Symbol, middle X coordinates and detection percentage
                        captcha_array.append([category_index[Symbol].get('name'), mid_x, scores[0][i]])

        # rearange array acording to X coordinates datected
        for number in range(20):
            for captcha_number in range(len(captcha_array)-1):
                if captcha_array[captcha_number][1] > captcha_array[captcha_number+1][1]:
                    temporary_captcha = captcha_array[captcha_number]
                    captcha_array[captcha_number] = captcha_array[captcha_number+1]
                    captcha_array[captcha_number+1] = temporary_captcha


        # Find average distance between detected symbols
        average = 0
        captcha_len = len(captcha_array)-1
        while captcha_len > 0:
            average += captcha_array[captcha_len][1]- captcha_array[captcha_len-1][1]
            captcha_len -= 1
        # Increase average distance error
        average = average/(len(captcha_array)+average_distance_error)

        
        captcha_array_filtered = list(captcha_array)
        captcha_len = len(captcha_array)-1
        while captcha_len > 0:
            # if average distance is larger than error distance
            if captcha_array[captcha_len][1]- captcha_array[captcha_len-1][1] < average:
                # check which symbol has higher detection percentage
                if captcha_array[captcha_len][2] > captcha_array[captcha_len-1][2]:
                    del captcha_array_filtered[captcha_len-1]
                else:
                    del captcha_array_filtered[captcha_len]
            captcha_len -= 1

        # Get final string from filtered CAPTCHA array
        captcha_string = ""
        for captcha_letter in range(len(captcha_array_filtered)):
            captcha_string += captcha_array_filtered[captcha_letter][0]
        return captcha_string
```

==================================================================================================

Comment: @ThomasSablik If the CPU usage is 10-20% the bottleneck is obviously not the programming language but I/O.

Comment: @Selcuk What I/O are you talking about? I can't see any I/O in the logic part.

Comment: @ThomasSablik No idea. Those functions are not even being called, so there is probably more to this code. In any case, a low CPU usage cannot be explained by the programming language. C++ does not automatically use multiple cores for the same algorithm. The OP should probably parallelise their algorithm and run multiple threads/processes.

Comment: I think 20~30% is already 100% of your core. To run it faster, you need to paralize it. Maybe check out [how to use tensforflow on a GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

Comment: @superbrain It uses 100% of **one core** for me. What you are seeing is the total CPU usage over multiple CPUs, which I explained in my comment above. You probably have 4 cores (25% for a single Python process).

Comment: @Selcuk Of course you can parallelize this code to make it 4 times faster. But there are many nested loops and conditions. That's a bottleneck in Python. Using a compiled language usually makes it 10 times faster or even more. That's the reason why most logic is implemented as C library in Python, JavaScript, Matlab, ...

Comment: Furthermore, what are you trying to accomplish? From what I read, you are looking for captchas. Are you using the fastest algorithm available? Could there be a better way to approach what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @superbrain No, because we don't see the rest of the code and I assumed that the OP is talking about one CPU (I might be wrong in that assumption).

Comment: @ThomasSablik It is not that simple as JIT compilers _can be_ faster, but in any case, the lowest hanging fruit is to run multiple processes using the same language/algorithm; not rewrite the whole thing in a different (and possibly unfamiliar to the OP) language.

Comment: @Selcuk That depends on the OP. For me Python is a prototyping language and C++ is a production language. The lowest hanging fruit is to write production code. That's my workflow for many years. Create a proof of concept with Matlab or Python and write realtime code with C++.

Comment: Python may take more time because it is interpreted, sure, but most of the heavy processing things the autor is doing is being done by tensorflow, which is written in both C and use numpy, which is also written in C. So after it has been compiled, it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker There are two functions. The first functions `load_model` calls tf. Changing the language won't improve it. But the second function `inference` has many nested loops and conditions. Depending on the number of iterations this can be very slow in Python. Using numpy or tf for `inference` is one way to improve the performance. Another way is to rewrite this logic in Cython.

Comment: But you should always try to optimize your code starting from the bottleneck. Applying a algorithm to an image is probably much more processing intensive than running those for's.

Comment: So the first step should be to profile the code to find the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments discussion, 20~30% is probably already the maximum processing power your CPU has, as it can only use one core. That's because Python (unlike [golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106526/parallel-processing-in-golang/44403016#44403016), for example) is not easily parallelised. Therefore, you might benefit from parallelising your code. Considering you are using tensorflow, this [guide to how to use a GPU with tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) will probably interest you.